# How do I track what people are doing in my app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, analytics

So I just finished my first app with javascript and phonegap build and Im pleased with the results.

But now Im wondering how do I find out what parts of the app people are using?

Is there some kinda analytics (google?? or something else?) that I should add?

Should I update the code to add some kind of counter for each link?

Im new to the whole app-analytics thing so Im totally lost. Any help (not looking for code examples) about what my options are is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics would be a good choice in most cases indeed. You can use their basic code snippets to add tracking, or if you have more sophisticated scenarios, you can fire custom "pageviews" and "events".